# How to sort a dynamic array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, date, sorting

I have a dynamic array created like this:

```
window.IDarray = [];
```

And I have a dictionary created like this:

```
window.itemdictionary = {};
```

The length of `window.IDarray` is the same as `window.itemdictionary`.
And the values of `window.IDarray` are unique. Also the values of `window.IDarray` are the keys to the `window.itemdictionary`.

The datatype of the "value" of any key in `window.itemdictionary` is also a dictionary that contains a key called `"modified"` and the value is a string date of the format example `"Mon May 28 11:20:46 EDT 2012"`.

What is the best way to sort the values of `window.IDarray`, so that going from index `0` to the end of `window.IDarray`, its corresponding dates in `window.itemdictionary` are getting farther from the current date? (i.e. index `0` will give closest date to the current date, and index `n` will give the date farthest away).

Comment: My answer assumes you just want to sort the dates chronologically, not say yesterday is closer to today than two days from now is but tomorrow is closer to today than two days ago. If that's wrong, you'll need to adjust the function to do absolute value math on the difference between `new Date()` and `date_a` and `date_b` and then compare the differences for the result of your comparator function.

Comment: please give sample data to get an appropriate solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use a custom sort function, see [Array.sort from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fsort#Example.3A_Sorting_maps).

First, in order to sort by a date, your `"modified": "Mon May 28 11:20:46 EDT 2012"` needs to be converted to a format that can be used for comparisons, using `Date.parse()`.

```
var tempItemDictionary = [];   // use temp array to hold the timestamp
// convert dates first
for (var i = 0, item = null; i < IDarray.length; i++) {
    item = itemDictionary[IDarray[i]];
    tempItemDictionary[IDarray[i]] = {
        timestamp: Date.parse(item.modified)    // convert date to timestamp
    };
}
```

Then we run the `IDarray` through `.sort()` using the custom sorting function:

```
IDarray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return tempItemDictionary[b].timestamp - tempItemDictionary[a].timestamp;
});
```

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/788bs/1/

Comment: It would be better to do the conversion in custom sorting function to avoid modifying the original data.

Comment: @tracevipin  Yes, can use another array to hold the timestamp and sort that. It also depends if that timestamp data will be used again later on.

Comment: Agree. If timestamp will be needed again it is better to save it. Depends on the requirement.

Comment: @tracevipin I like your suggestion, I have updated the code to use a temporary array to hold the timestamp for sorting, this way the original data in `itemDictionary` is untouched.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array with a custom comparator function parameter like:

```
IDarray.sort(function(a, b) {
    var date_a, date_b;
    try {
        date_a = Date.parse(itemdictionary[a]['modified'];
        date_b = Date.parse(itemdictionary[b]['modified'];
        return date_a - date_b;
    } catch (e) {
        /* Some smart exception handling for malformed strings? */
    }
});
```

Comment: Probably not a good idea to call `Date.parse` every time a comparison is made, for large sets you're going to be doing n^2 conversions of dates :( Along the same lines of performance, you don't want to use `try catch` inside your comparison function because each time it goes into the `try` block, the scope chain is augmented so that it can do the *catch* later when something bad happens. Might be better using `if` conditions.

Comment: Agreed about `try…catch` but there's no way around the `Date.parse` thing since that's how the sort is required. I agree it's going to be pretty slow regardless…

Answer (score 0):

```
window.IDarray = [];
window.itemdictionary = {
    "key0": { modified: "Mon May 28 11:20:46 EDT 2012" },
    "key1": { modified: "Mon May 28 11:20:46 EDT 2012" },
    "key2": { modified: "Mon Sep 20 20:35:15 EDT 2010" },
    "key3": { modified: "Mon May 10 10:07:16 EDT 2010" },
    "key4": { modified: "Tue May 10 10:07:16 EDT 2011" }
};

var sortByDate = function(key1, key2) {
    var date1 = new Date(window.itemdictionary[key1].modified.toString());
    var date2 = new Date(window.itemdictionary[key2].modified.toString());
    return date2 - date1;
};
// lt IE9
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/) {
        var len = this.length >>> 0;
        var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
        from = (from < 0) ? Math.ceil(from) : Math.floor(from);
        if (from < 0)
          from += len;

        for (; from < len; from++) {
          if (from in this && this[from] === elt)
            return from;
        }
        return -1;
    };
}

window.itemdictionary.currDate = { modified: new Date().toString() };
window.IDarray = Object.keys(window.itemdictionary);
console.log('before', window.IDarray);
window.IDarray.sort(sortByDate);

delete window.itemdictionary.currDate;
window.IDarray.splice(window.IDarray.indexOf('currDate'), 1);
console.log('after', window.IDarray);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nYWmZ/1/